# Unable to access the internet after uninstalling python from synaptic

Tags: python, internet, ethernet

I uninstalled python from synaptic and then reinstalled it using terminal. It worked fine but now after I restarted my PC when I log in to KDE session I just get a black screen with a cursor and when I log in to Lxqt session I have no access to the internet even though I am connected through Ethernet.

Comment: It is an extremely bad idea to uninstall Python from any flavor of Ubuntu, because the system heavily depends on it. The simplest thing you can do is reinstall the system.

Comment: You you remove `python`, all tools that rely on `python` will no longer operate, so you've reduced your system to a very simple one (many functions will no longer work - that is expected as you've removed a necessary tool for your *unstated* release).  You've not provided OS & release details; but manually installing the *python minimal* (vague as your release is unknown) will bring back some features allowing you to more easily fix the rest. Logs will tell you what you removed from your *unstated* release.

Comment: Try to get the one version of python that was distributed with your Ubuntu version as system-python. New versions come with 2 pythons: python2.7 (called as just python) and python3.x (called as python3).